# JNDI Names -- Is Prefix "jdbc/" needed?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, datasource, jndi, tomcat6

What's up with JNDI names? I'm trying to get a javax.sql.DataSource using the new annotations feature of Java 5. It's not working for me, so I want to ask...

I have a  in my web.xml, inside of it is an  element. I'm switching between "jdbc/MyDB" and "MyDB". Neither makes my class-based DataSource work (it's always null) but in another example I've created using taglibs, both of these JNDI names work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not. It is just the convention so that it's clear to everyone what resource it is.

You can even name it `k34ug6i2u3dn234uy5f`, but that would lead to future maintenance problems.

Comment: But what if the resource was explicitly named like "jdbc/MyResource"? Should it be referenced as "jdbc/MyResource"? Or will "MyResource" suffice? We have a weird problem... The resource is created with "jdbc/" prefix, but in the code it's referenced without one. Application runs normally, but the Arquillian tests fail :(